# Fusionar las líneas que comparten la misma clave en una linea

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Tengo [un Dataframe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RZTL9iEVW2uqepZVNPkJ5vt-IXzv66md/view?usp=sharing) y me gustaria hacer otra columna que que Combinen las columnas cuyo nombre comienza con la misma `value` en `Answer` y `QID`.

Es por decir, teniendo el siguiente Dataframe

```
    QID     Category    Text    QType   Question:   Answer0     Answer1     Country
0   16  Automotive  Access to car   Single  Do you have access to a car?    I own a car/cars    I own a car/cars  UK
1   16  Automotive  Access to car   Single  Do you have access to a car?    I lease/ have a company car     I lease/have a company car  UK
2   16  Automotive  Access to car   Single  Do you have access to a car?    I have access to a car/cars     I have access to a car/cars     UK
3   16  Automotive  Access to car   Single  Do you have access to a car?    No, I don’t have access to a car/cars   No, I don't have access to a car    UK
4   16  Automotive  Access to car   Single  Do you have access to a car?    Prefer not to say   Prefer not to say   UK
```

Necesito Obtener como Resultado:

```
        QID     Category    Text    QType   Question:   Answer0     Answer1     Answer2    Answer3  Country    Answers
    0   16  Automotive  Access to car   Single  Do you have access to a car?    I own a car/cars    I lease/ have a company car      I have access to a car/cars    No, I don’t have access to a car/cars    UK    ['I own a car/cars', 'I lease/ have a company car'   ,'I have access to a car/cars', 'No, I don’t have access to a car/cars', 'Prefer not to say     Prefer not to say']
```

Hasta ahora tengo lo siguiente:

```
# lazy - want first of all attributes except QID and Answer columns
agg = {col:"first" for col in list(df.columns) if col!="QID" and "Answer" not in col}
# get a list of all answers in Answer0 for a QID
agg = {**agg, **{"Answer0":lambda s: list(s)}}

# helper function for row call.  not needed but makes more readable
def ans(r, i):
    return "" if i>=len(r["AnswerT"]) else r["AnswerT"][i]

# split list from aggregation back out into columns using assign
# rename Answer0 to AnserT from aggregation so that it can be referred to.  
# AnswerT drop it when don't want it any more
dfgrouped = df.groupby("QID").agg(agg).reset_index().rename(columns={"Answer0":"AnswerT"}).assign(
    Answer0=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: ans(r, 0), axis=1),
    Answer1=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: ans(r, 1), axis=1),
    Answer2=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: ans(r, 2), axis=1),
    Answer3=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: ans(r, 3), axis=1),
    Answer4=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: ans(r, 4), axis=1),
    Answer5=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: ans(r, 5), axis=1),
    Answer6=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: ans(r, 6), axis=1),
).drop("AnswerT", axis=1)

print(dfgrouped.to_string(index=False))
```

Funciona bien pero hay veces que tengo más de seis respuestas. ¿Cómo lo haces dinámico en términos del número de respuestas dadas a un par de (`QID`, `Question`:)?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby(COLUMNAS_CRITERIO)[COLUMNA_VALOR].apply(list)
```

Aquí COLUMNAS_CRITERIO es la lista de columnas que vas a agrupar (value, Answer y QID), y COLUMNA_VALOR es la columna con el valor que se va a repetir (Answers?).